# Date.toString comparison

Tags: javascript

We've found in our code the next line (yes, you can ask why it even exists, but it does):

```
console.log(new Date(2015, 10, 9).toString() > new Date(2015, 9, 10).toString())
// Returns false

console.log(new Date(2015, 5, 9).toString() > new Date(2015, 4, 10).toString())
// Returns true
```

We don't understand how it works exactly, so hopefully someone can explain.

Comment: I would assume its expecting Year Month Day

Comment: Well I would argue that it does *not* work.

Comment: @ChrisMorris yes indeed: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Syntax

Comment: See [Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/492994/1048572) for how to do it properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString) returns string representation of date in the following format

```
new Date(2015, 10, 9).toString();
```

> "Mon Nov 09 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"

First line

```
console.log(new Date(2015, 10, 9).toString() > new Date(2015, 9, 10).toString())
```

is `false` **because `M > S` is false**

Second line

```
console.log(new Date(2015, 5, 9).toString() > new Date(2015, 4, 10).toString())
```

is `true` **because `T > M` is true**

Answer (score 1):

I did this on node, see the output, it should be self-explaintory

```
> console.log(new Date(2015, 10, 9).toString())
Mon Nov 09 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (+08)

> console.log( new Date(2015, 4, 10).toString())
Sun May 10 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (+08)

> console.log(new Date(2015, 5, 9).toString())
Tue Jun 09 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (+08)

> console.log(new Date(2015, 4, 10).toString())
Sun May 10 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (+08)
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically the above expressions evaluate to:

```
console.log("Mon Nov 09 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)" > "Sat Oct 10 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)");
//false

console.log("Tue Jun 09 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)" > "Sun May 10 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)");
//true
```

Now, why is that? JavaScript compares strings [Lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

Meaning the first letters of each strings get compared first according to their alphabetical order.

---

**First expression**: `S` is later in the alphabet. Therefore its greater than `M`.

**Second expression**: `T` is later in the alphabet. Therefore its greater than `S`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not much of an expert in string manipulation, but for the first case ...

`new Date(2015, 10, 9).toString()`

gives the date in string depending on the region you are in, in my case, it is

`Mon Nov 09 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)`

and for   `new Date(2015, 9, 10).toString()`

I get   `"Sat Oct 10 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)"`

Now, the when a comparison is done between two string, in this case it is **>**, the javascript engine compares the first character of two strings, and alphabetically **M** comes before **S**, so the first console.log gives **false**, as **M** is not greater than **S**.

Similar explanation goes for the second case where the character **T** comes after **S**, hence **T** is greater than **S** is **true**.